# How do I get rid of escape characters created by os.path.join?

Tags: python, windows, path, escaping

With `os.walk` I walk through a structure, for which I create the paths with `os.path.join`. Then I want to use one of those strings to open an image. However, `os.path.join` creates escape characters (`\r`) while joining the path, and then cannot use the same string to open an image.

How do I avoid getting backslashes in `os.path.join` in the first place?

code:

```
def filepaths(directory):

    files = []
    for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in filenames:
            files.append os.path.join(root, filename)
    return files

images = (filepath for filepath in filepaths(dir) if (filepath.lower().endswith('jpg')))
pic = max(things, key=os.path.getctime)

Image.open(pic)
```

Answer (score 3):

`os.path.join` does *not* insert escape characters, only the appropriate path separators.

```
>>> root = r"C:\Users\me\AppData"
>>> filename = "myfile.jpg"
>>> print (os.path.join(root, filename))
C:\Users\me\AppData\myfile.jpg
```

But if you do this instead:

```
>>> root = r"C:\Users\me\AppData"
>>> filename = "myfile.jpg"
>>> os.path.join(root, filename)
'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\myfile.jpg'
```

you will see escape characters, because that is what you would have to put in a string literal in Python code. To see this, try comparing the two representations:

```
>>> r"C:\Users\me\AppData\myfile.jpg" == 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\myfile.jpg'
True
```

The first representation is a *raw string* literal, where backslashes only mean themselves. The second representation is a regular string literal, where you need to have genuine backslashes doubled because they would otherwise be interpreted as escape characters. As you can see, the two representations may look different, but are really two different ways of displaying the same data.

If you are seeing escape characters in filenames in error messages, that is to be expected. It doesn't mean that your call to `open()` had a string with too many backslashes in it. Error messages are like that so that you can see potential non-printing characters in the filename.

Comment: If os.path.join would treat the characters properly, any variable having stored a valid joined path should be able to be used to open the file. However, this clearly doesn't happen.

We had to solve it by replacing os.path.join by os.path.normpath(path + '/' + file)

The path.join somehow creates an unreadable filename

Comment: If there were a bug of that severity in `os.path.join()` I think it would have been discovered by now. You have presented what you say the problem is, but no actual data and no actual error messages. Without that it is very hard for us to say where your code might be going wrong. `os.path.normpath()` might be fixing a problem you think is in `os.path.join()` but is really somewhere in your code.

Comment: so how do we use such a variable as a parameter?

Comment: @mckenzm Asking a  question as a comment to another question that was closed as unsatisfactory 4 years ago is unlikely to get a useful response. I suggest you ask your own question explaining what you want to do, and why you are having trouble getting `os.path` functions to do what you want.

Comment: @BoarGules Apologies, partially rhetotical - we use path add and let it sort it out.